# Unable to connect to AWS-RDS MySql Database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When creating the database in `AWS RDS console`, I can connect to the database using `MySql Workbench`, but after some time, when `restarting` the MySql Workbench and try to connect to the same database then I am getting an error `Your connection attempt failed for user 'username' from your host to server at <endpoint>`.

This is strange, but I am facing this issue, don't know why. I tried to be logged in to AWS when connecting to the database.

Also, when I try to connect from my PHP script, it always gets Timed Out, even for the first time.

Link to my demo site:- http://phpdynamicappone-env.xgbztdyxar.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/ (click on `view posts`)

Comment: Did you make your RDS public and allow your IP to access it on the Security Group?

Comment: Yes it has Public Accessibility, but I am not sure about the IP, on the Security Group it is showing 2 records

1. `rds-launch-wizard-4 (sg-033ec9fe7640117bc)  -  CIDR/IP - Inbound  -  47.29.235.144/32`

2. `rds-launch-wizard-4 (sg-033ec9fe7640117bc)  -  CIDR/IP - Outbound  - 0.0.0.0/0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are two cases to connect with an AWS RDS -**

**Publicly -**
1. You need to select the Publicly Accessible option in RDS configuration.
2. Your RDS Security group, needs to allow MYSQL traffic from your 
local/server/security group

**Private -**
1. If your RDS is Private, you'll need to create a Bastion Host.
2. Allow MYSQL Traffic to RDS, from the Bastion Host's Security group.
3. Allow SSH Traffic from your local, to the Bastion Host's Security group
4. Create Tunneling to your RDS via Bastion Host,
This can be done via using "Standard TCP/IP over SSH" method in MySql Workbench

Comment: Yes it has Public Accessibility, but I am not sure about the IP, on the Security Group it is showing 2 records

1. `rds-launch-wizard-4 (sg-033ec9fe7640117bc)  -  CIDR/IP - Inbound  -  47.29.235.144/32`


2. `rds-launch-wizard-4 (sg-033ec9fe7640117bc)  -  CIDR/IP - Outbound  - 0.0.0.0/0`